# Is there a way to get xplanetfx working in Ubuntu again?

Tags: configuration, desktop-background

Back when most linux users were installing packages manually there was this program called XplanetFX which was a frontend for xplanet.  It would make the setup of near real-time wallpapers of globes or maps of the earth with clouds and would update them from time to time to be indicative of recent weather patterns.  It would also show the areas lit by the sun and those not lit realistically as if viewed from space.
I was hoping to get that program running again,so far I've gotten to this point

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xplanetfx : Depends: python (>= 2.5) but it is not installable
             Depends: python-gtk2 but it is not installable
             Depends: python-glade2 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm not sure this is installable under the default window manager.

Is this a lost cause?  I haven't been able to find any programs that provide the features of xplanetfx.  It was a gui frontend for xplanet and also automatically downloaded cloud files and updated the wallpaper accordingly.

Comment: Python 2 is deprecated, and I would suggest that if somethi8ng needs Python 2 it won't work.  Also GTK2 is *dead* so you won't be able to use that in modern Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I tried to install it with Synaptic but the same result. Xplanet installs and runs in a terminal but I don't know how to use it. You can type `man xplanet` for the man page.

Comment: I tried to send a message on [their blog](https://mein-neues-blog.de/2017/05/07/xplanetfx-1-6-13-minor-bugfix/#respond) but I don't think it went through